# What repository can I save to without having admin rights?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm facing a problem with an Internet application I'm working on right now (programming in C#).

I have to create a report and then send it via email to a certain user. After I create the report, I save it first into a temporary file, then attached it to the email giving the file path.

It's working on my computer because I have the administrator right, but it doesn't for my coworkers who don't have the admin right on their computer.

The file path I'm using is:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache), 
    fileName
);
```

Is there any temporary repository I can use that doesn't require admin rights?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the built in `MailMessage` class in .Net?  What is generating your report?

Comment: Is this really an ASP.NET web application?  Why are you trying to save a file created using your web site to the server's InternetCache?  of course this will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the built in mail classes in .Net, there's really no reason you need to write the attachment to a file at all, unless whatever is generating the report requires it.

This would work, assuming your report generator doesn't require file output and can just return bytes.

```
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(); //do whatever else you need to do here to configure this
            byte[] report = GetReport();//whatever your report generator is
            MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
            //add your other mail fields (body, to, cc, subject etc)
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(report))
            {
                m.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream,"reportfile.xls"));//just guessing, use the right filename for your attachment type
                smtpClient.Send(m);  //note that we send INSIDE this using block, because it will not actually read the stream until you send
                                     //and you want to make sure not to dispose the stream before it reads it
            }
```

Comment: I'd upvote this if it weren't for the fact that you gotta assume he can't email the report right away until he tells ya.

Comment: @gangelo: I realize that, which is why I explained it, but I still think it's worth posting because IMHO writing temp files is not a good solution no matter what.  Even if it is some obscure file-only report generator... it's time to get a new report generator

Comment: NOW DON'T GET TESTY WITH ME; I was going to vote you up if the solution works for him ;)

Comment: @Brook Thank you I'm gonna try to do it this way.

Answer (score 3):

Considering your ASP.NET tag, you should look at using [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

How are you attaching it to the email? From the sounds of your question it appears that all you're doing is giving them the path to the file you create, rather than attaching it (as, once you attach it, it's embedded in the email and thus there are no paths involved).

If the web application is creating the temporary file then you can use the app_data folder (which is usually writable), and get a unique file name by using Path.GetRandomFileName().

So, something like

```
var myTemporaryFileName = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data", 
                                       Path.GetRandomFileName());
```

Then write your file to this temporary file name, then attach it to the email

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage("recipient@example.com", "", ""               
                      "subject",
                      "mail body");

Attachment data = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
disposition.FileName = "thefilenameyouwanttouseintheemail.ext";
message.Attachments.Add(data);
```

Now you can send it.

Don't forget to clean them up after though!